# Qt dock neighbour widget behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have two Qt widgets in the window. One of them is QDockWidget, and another one is just QWidget.
When I drag the QDockWidget, the default behaviour of the another widget is moving without changing its size. And I want it to fill the whole window except dock widget, and to change its size programmatically when I drag QDockWidget. Hwo to do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set container horizontal policy as "fixed"